# Is there a variable I could use to identify the project directory at the command line options in the project properties in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, cassini, ultidev-cassini

In Visual Studio 2008 when you go to properties of a project (an ASP.NET MVC one at least) you have the option to run an external program. There are three parts for it: the path to the program, the command line options, the working directory.

I need to pass the root of my web application as a command line argument. I don't want to hardcode the path in my machine in that directory. Is there some sort of (environment) variable I could use?

Background: I'm trying to run UltiDev Cassini because VS' Cassini is 32bit only. I think this is the right way to run it, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You will find the list of all the variables that you can use, with their values, at the following place:

- Open the properties for your project, go the 'Debugging' node
- click in the 'Command Arguments' field, a drop-down symbol appears on the right of the  field
- open the drop-down, choose 'Edit'
- click on the 'Macros' button, et voilà...

This shows the list of all the variables you can use, along with their values.  You should be able to find one that suits your needs...

Answer (score 0):

Try a $(ProjectDir) or $(SolutionDir) variable, or some other one from a list documented here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pablo, you can customize and compile [CassiniDev](http://CassiniDev.codeplex.com) as x64 and get exactly what you want.

Custom configuration via .config is on the todo for the next release.